# Is there a way to rewrite this matrix equation to eliminate inverse matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\mathbf{K}\in\operatorname{GL}(n)$. Consider the following constraint:

$$\mathbf{u}^{\top} \left( \mathbf{K^{\top} K} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{v} = 0 \tag{1}$$

This constraint appears in some computer vision applications when dealing with camera calibration. The form of $(1)$ involves heavy computations which leads me to ask:

Is there a way to rewrite $(1)$ so that when checking for this constraint we don't have to compute matrix inverse as it is in many cases numerically unfeasible?

Comment: instead of Cholesky, you'd be better off computing $QR$ factorization on $K$.  This implicitly gives you Cholesky, has less steps and saves the multiplication of $K^T$ times $K$ which likely induces numeric issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that ${\bf K}^{T}{\bf K}$ is symmetric and positive definite. Therefore you can take advantage of its Cholesky decomposition to efficiently compute its inverse.